# How i can offer a licensing Android application

Tags: android, licensing

I puphished a free version of my application and i'm going to publish a paid version with more functions. This paid version is licensing and i want offer few of them. How can i proceed?

Comment: You can't control who purchases the app using the Google Market (I assume this is what you are using). You will have to explore other options, including handling the licences by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here:

If you wish to charge *ongoing* license fees for your *free* app, you do nothing more than modify your app to handle [In-App Purchases](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) and you're done.

Now if you wish to *charge* for this same app (as well as maybe licensing), you will have to publish a *new* app to the Android Market, set your price etc. Same thing applies here if you wish to do In-App purchases.

If it wasn't already obvious, any and all purchases *within* your application have to use In-App Billing (Android Market rules).

Comment: I think he wants to control who purchases the app. That's not possible with google market. Not sure about other markets, but it seems unlikely that they support this.

Comment: @aromero Yeah for sure. As far as controlling _who_ purchases the app will be a no-go with Google Market.

Comment: I will try this solution: Put the people to whom I want to offer application in test account on a fully functional licensing application that I shall put online, but I shall never publish...