# Can selective licensing be done using Google play?

Tags: android

I have an app which is planned to be released in several phases:

1. Testing phase using email distribution to small testing population (in-process).
2. To a small group of users. It will be a diverse group geographically and it is important that the app is not given / spread to wider audience.
3. For broad distribution to who ever might want it, free or paid (logically google play).

Given this, can the Google play licensing scheme be used to facilitate the first phase? I read in the following link that google does not want any form of selective distribution (other than testing). I did not see any references for selectively enabling an app (second link).

[How i can offer a licensing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978571/how-i-can-offer-a-licensing-android-application)

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html

The alternative for phase 1 would be to develop an authentication mechanism with a server using a distributed key. The key would be matched against either a uuid or google id on a server before the app could be activated. Distribution to new users would be involve providing a new key. 
Comment appreciated on both.

Answer (score 0):

The Google licensing scheme (LVL) only works for paid applications. What it does is basically check that the current app is in the history of purchases associated with a particular Google account. If it is, you have legitimate paid user; if not, well, something went wrong, or somebody is trying to pirate your app. It has had mixed success. It doesn't allow you to control who can use your app in any other way.

So if you want to distribute a private beta, you can either:

1. Distribute directly via email, etc. (first phase)
2. Host on Google Play and develop your own activation scheme (product code, etc). Then only the people who receive the code can actually use the app. (phase two)
3. (1+2) Distribute via your web site to anyone, but require activation. (phase two)

For 2., you are bound to get some 1-stars from people who don't read the description/instructions ('Doesn't work', 'Activation required, boo', etc.), so it is a good idea to use a separate package from the final one (com.myapp.beta, etc.).